# How to correct dB from antenna factors

Tags: rf, antenna, emc

I am using a TBMA1 biconical antenna from TekBox to make emissions measurements on my hardware ([datasheet](https://www.tekbox.com/product/TBMA1_Manual.pdf).)

I want to confirm that I understand how the antenna factor plays into dB correction. At 190 MHz at 1 meter the antenna has a factor of 16.71 dB/m. I calculated a gain of -0.91 dBi, so really a loss, using this formula:

[image]

If I measure 50 dBuV/M, I have to add 0.91 on top of it, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: You are correct.

The equipment (I assume a spectrum analyzer) does not know the gain vs. frequency characteristic of the antenna you're using for measurement, so, on top of the measured dBuV/m you need to subtract the gain of your antenna at the corresponding frequency.

Subtract -0.91 means you add the 0.91 dB.